# Web API (Rest) working in local host but not in server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created one web API which is working fine in my local machine, but when I moved it into the server it is giving 401 error. Could anyone please help me with this

This is the first web api we are doing in our application.

Comment: 401 is 'unauthorized'. Do you have authentication set up in your application? Is there any default authentication on the server, in IIS? How are you deploying the app - is this Azure?

Comment: Which code are you running? Which server do you use? Give some code to clarify your question.

Comment: Make sure you are allowing anonymous access to root directory !!!

Comment: There is a lot more information required to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add and set the Authorization atribute in header of each request you are sending to your API. Or you will need to set anonymous authentication on your server.